# how to fake / unit test Azure Storage Queue?

Tags: c#, azure, unit-testing, azure-storage, azure-storage-queues

I am trying to find a way to test some code I have that will query an azure storage queue.  For now, I have been asked to create my own local in memory queue class that simulates the upstream Azure queue.
At this point, I'm trying to see if I can create a sample message in a fake queue so the callee of my class has some data to work with.

So I'm trying to do something like this:

```
using Azure.Storage.Queues.Models;
namespace Widgets.Tests.Queues
{
    public class InMemoryAzureMessageQueue : IAzureQueueClient
    {
        public string DequeueMessage(QueueMessage message)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public QueueMessage[] GetMessages()
        {
           //pseudocode
           QueueMessage qm = new QueueMessage();
           QueueMessage[] listqm = new QueueMessage[];
           qm.messageID = xxx;
           qm.messageBody = "hello";

           listqm.add(qm);
           return listqm;

        }

        public bool HasMesssages()
        {
            return true; 
        }
    }
 }
```

When I try to create "qm" I'm getting the following error message:
'QueueMessage' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

**What I've Tried So Far:**

I have tried to "go to defintion" while clicking on QueueMessage just to see what the constructor looks like.  But when I do, I get an error saying that there is no definition found.

The description of the class says this:

```
The object returned in the QueueMessageList array when calling Get Messages on a Queue.
```

Maybe I can't just create a message like this?

I'm really green at .NET and all things Azure.
Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you read any docs / googled on that error once? It's a very trivial error to solve. It basically means that you need to pass the required arguments to the constructor of QueueMessage. Are you using an IDE like Visual Studio? If you `ctrl` + `click` on `QueueMessage`, the IDE will probably bring you to the definition of the type, where you can see the constructor and its required arguments. You can also just google `QueueMessage` and see the required arguments in the docs.

Comment: Yes actually I already tried to "go to definition" but it says No Definition found for QueueMessage.  I've confirmed that I have the right library added at the top of my code... I'll update my question to include these details.

Comment: You might need plugins to go to definition for code that is outside of your own project. After googling for QueueMessage I found this page which shows you how to mock create a queue message: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.queues.models.queuesmodelfactory.queuemessage?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`QueueMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.queues.models.queuemessage?view=azure-dotnet) class does not contain an accessible constructor. You can however build a message using the [`QueuesModelFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.queues.models.queuesmodelfactory.queuemessage?view=azure-dotnet), which was designed for mocking these messages:

```
public QueueMessage[] GetMessages()
{
    QueueMessage qm = QueuesModelFactory.QueueMessage(
        messageId: "xxx",
        popReceipt: "",
        messageText: "hello",
        dequeueCount: 0);
    QueueMessage[] listqm = new QueueMessage[1];

    listqm[0] = qm;
    return listqm;
}
```